# How to trigger an update of several C++ classes when a shared member of all the classes is updated

Tags: c++, class

Lets say we have a scenario as follows (what I have tried up to now in some very striped down version):

```
class A{
  std::vector<int> ma;
};

class B{
  A param;
  // members that depend on "param"
  int mb1; 
  // members that DO NOT depend on "param"
  int mb2;

  B(const A &p, const int &x) param(p), mb2(x) {
    make_mb1();
  };

  void make_mb1(){
     mb2 = std::accumulate(param.begin(), param.end(), 0);  
  };
};

int main{
  A a({1,2,3});
  B b1(a,1), b2(a,2), b3(a,3);

  return 0;
}
```

When the contents of `a` are updated I would like all instances of `B` class that have `a` to updated them selves accordingly, so I want a behavior something like this:

```
int main{
  A a({1,2,3});
  B b1(a,...), b2(a,...), b3(a,...);

  // first case
  a = std::vector({4,5,6});
  // b1, b2, b3 trigger an updated of members that depend on param 

  // second case
  b1.param = std::vector({7,8,9});
  // b1, b2, b3 trigger an updated of members that depend on param 

  return 0;
}
```

How can I do this so that all I need to do as a user is to simply updated the contents of `a` through its instance (first case above) or through any member instances (second case above) and then `b1,b2,b3` trigger an internal update (perhaps using `make_mb1`) of members automatically without needing further code in `main`? If this is a concept with a name I am more than happy to just get the name and I will research it (I have tried to figure this out but can't seam to find how this would be called so I am having a hard time figuring out what to look up).

Comment: Looks like you need an [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). `B` objects would register themselves as observers in the owner of vector (e.g. `A`) and then any update to the owner of vector will call given function on registered observers.

Comment: That is excellent advise, I am looking into it, but from first glance and it seams like what I need to do.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen actually this pretty much exactly what I need. If you post it as a answer I am glad to upvote it as the solution.